# When using Html.Action in layout getting error: Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'll try to keep this as brief as possible.. I have a `ViewResult` that I am rendering on my _layout.cshtml page. This ViewResult is in a controller called CommonController where I am keeping some actions and data that I need on every page. If it matters, my `ViewResult` is a simple form.

**ViewResult and the CommonController**

```
[Authorize]
public class CommonController : AuthenticatedBaseController
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ViewResult OrgSwitch()
    {
        //do stuff
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public RedirectToRouteResult OrgSwitch(string UserOrgs)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Recruiter", new { orgId = UserOrgs, area = "InkScroll" });
    }
}
```

In my _Layout.cshtml page I render it like so:

```
@Html.Action("OrgSwitch", new { controller = "Common", area = "MyArea" })
```

This is all working fine, but now I am adding some functionality elsewhere in the app. I had asp.net mvc5 scaffold out a controller and views for a class I need to CRUD against. Just the quick and dirty forms so I can test a couple of things. I am going into the create page to add a new item. **warning, it is mvc scaffolding, very ugly**:

```
@model inkScroll.Models.Vacancy

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Vacancy</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobRef, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobRef)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobRef)
        </div>
    </div>
    // lots more ugly code
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

When I click 'submit' in the controller it does the usually validation checks and stuff. If my form **is valid**, there is no problem. If there are modelstate issues, I get the child action error.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** to clarify, the razor page you see is a scaffolded page that posts to a seperate `JobsController`. The data being passed into the post of the 'create' page is working fine, I am only getting the error if the model validation fails.

Comment: The parameter in your Post action does not match with the Model of your view. Have You modified the code just for posting here? And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: See edit, the Post action you see goes to a separate controller.

Comment: The error says that you can't redirect from a child action. Your child action is doing a redirect. Are you actually expecting a full page redirect and if so why not just send them to the right page in the first place?

Comment: @Chris this is where I am getting confused. I step through each part of the code on the post (when I know the model state will fail). The only thing that happens is it returns the same 'create' view with the passed in model, and it also obviously renders my layout page which the partial view I have on there. I don't see it performing redirects unless there is something low level I am missing. Stepping through the code takes me through the exact path as it does when I first load the page, as well as on successful postbacks. So why the error on the modalstate failure?

Comment: @davidisawesome: Ah. I had misread your post slightly. So if you put a breakpoint on the redirect you've quoted above it doesn't get hit at all? In case you are unaware it won't throw the exception immediately it gets to that redirect line, just when it comes to execute the result of that action which will be a bit later (though not much later usually but I can't guarantee that). Does the stack trace give any indications of the problem? It should at least confirm what view is giving the problem and may tell more. I can't remember precisely what the stack trace will look like...

Comment: @Chris I will take a look through it again this morning, post-coffee. I will update the question in a bit with those additional details.